# Is there possibility to specify a linear regression using a OLS from statsmodels in way that some coefficients are declare manually?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, coefficients

I want to build linear regression by using OLS from statsmodels. I have a question about manually declaration of coefficients for some explanatory variables.

**Is there possibility to parameterize a model in way that for 4 from 10 variables I will put manually coefficients and for rest the fit method will count the values of them?**

Or maybe you know a different way haw to do it?

Many thanks for all answers!

MP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in two steps. First you take those manual coefficients, multiply them with the corresponding ('manual') variables to get vectors, and subtract them from the target.
Then, you can take a normal OLS and get the coefficients of the remaining variables.

Say you have two variables, `x1` and `x2`, and want to set the weight for `w1`. You can simply infer

```
w2 =(x2**T * x2) ** (-1) * x2 ** T * (y - w1 * x1)
```

Comment: Thank for your response. Good idea, but after fitting the model I need to explore all variables separately. So I think that this solution is not exactly what I need.

Comment: What do you mean, you need to explore all variables separately? At this point you know `w1` and `w2`, so you can recreate the `w` vector. This approach remains valid when `w1` and `w2` are vectors.

Comment: Ok. After analyzed more your example, I understand what you mean. Thanks for the help.